# phone number validation regex in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I need to validate phone number in these formats 
`+1-541-754-3010 , (123) 986-5470 and 123-569-8740` I have given following regex

```
validates :phone, format: { with: /\A\(?\d{3}\)?[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}\z/,
                              message: I18n.t('global.errors.phone_format')}
```

It working for (123) 986-5470 and 123-569-8740 but not for

```
+1-541-754-3010
754-3010 Local
(541) 754-3010 Domestic
+1-541-754-3010 International
1-541-754-3010 Dialed in the US
001-541-754-3010 Dialed from Germany
191 541 754 3010 Dialed from France
```

Please guide me how to solve this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Like [`\A(?:\(?\d{3}\)?[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}|\+\d{2}[ ]\d{10})\z`](http://rubular.com/r/4WqdHSIEAI)?

Comment: In your requirements you don't say it needs to work for numbers starting with "+"

Comment: It needs to work for all the 3 numbers and do not accept any strings or any other special character arther that -,  (, ), space and +

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\A(?:\+?\d{1,3}\s*-?)?\(?(?:\d{3})?\)?[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}\z
```

You can another optional group .See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/20

Comment: Please go through question once

Comment: This looks like the best answer on this matter on the internet, and soo few votes it has :)

Comment: I wanted to thank you for sharing the regex101.com link. I used your solution along with the site to solve my problem!

Comment: Be careful using this particular regex if you're outside the USA. For instance with the above linked regex, `(029) 999 9999` is valid, but `(02) 9999 9999` is invalid. The former would be expected in USA, but the latter would be expected in Australia. If you need a regex for phone numbers outside America, or globally, then you may need something slightly less strict.

Answer (score 1):

More advanced case, for example with Ukrainian local phone numbers like
050 555 33 22

```
^(?:\+?\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\(?(?:\d{3})?\)?[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{2}[- ]?\d{2}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/YexwM5/3

Answer (score 0):

If you have E164 numbers, you can use a simple regexp

```rb
PHONE_NUMBER_REGEXP = /\+[0-9]+/ # e164
```